# Newly added users are not showing up For GSuite

Tags: api, synchronization, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace, google-directory-api

I am using the GSuite Admin SDK, Directory API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users) to add and list users,
After adding a new user (using this endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users) I try and check if that user exists in the user list or not (using this endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?customer=my_customer).

Every time I do these steps I could not find the newly created users, there seems to be a problem with synchronization.

Is there any solution for this without changing the access token?
thnx for the help.

Comment: Sounds like a propagation issue, how long after creating the users are you checking the endpoint?

Comment: First I tried checking directly after creating the user, after that, I delayed the check after 6 seconds. But the same outcome, the user is not there in the list.

Comment: I think it might be wise to wait longer than 6 seconds to check a REST API for resource updates...